# xcode, How do I add an image view that changes images depending on what I select in camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, camera

There is no view controller or any interfacebuilder, I want to build this with just code. I have the method setup where you can click on button to go to camera roll, but now I am lost on what to do next. I need a way to select an image and it will allow me to add the image to an image view. Any tips on what to do will be appreciated.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
[self.view addSubview: imgView];


UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)aMethod{

UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer was correct....but here is another way of looking at it....

As long as you have your code calling your photo album the next step you will need is:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

That will place the returned info into your selected imageView.....

What you have in your posted code is opening your photo library....the net step is to say OK....Ive finished picking my media....what am I going to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help :-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

as delegete of `imagePickerController`

You can get the image by **info** key :-

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

For more see this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html).

**info** is
a `dictionary` containing the **original image** and the **edited image**, If an image was picked; or a filesystem **URL** for the movie, if a movie was picked. The `dictionary` also contains any relevant editing information. The keys for this `dictionary` are listed in **Editing Information Keys**.

Comment: I don't think this helpful.

Comment: @FalconHawk - Why you dont think ??? Just because he has given a correct link to read it out yourself and you wanted the exact two lines ?

Comment: that is what i said hahaha